# How can I run "query session" using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, cmd

I would like to get the results from executing "query session" in the cmd.exe and Store them in a string variable using VB.NET. I have been searching for two days now and I cannot get to run the command, I will try to save the result once I get the command running.

It seems that VisualStudio executes cmd.exe but not the one in C:\Windows\System32.

```
        Dim process As System.Diagnostics.Process = New System.Diagnostics.Process
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K query session"
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = False
    process.Start()
    process.WaitForExit()
```

It returns error: 'query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a permission problem. You need to pass a user name and a password of an administrator user to your command

```
.....
process.StartInfo.UserName = "yourAdminUser"
process.StartInfo.Password = GetPassword()
.....


Public Function GetPassword() as String
     Dim ss = new SecureString()
     ss.AppendChar("p")
     ss.AppendChar("a")
     ss.AppendChar("s")
     ss.AppendChar("s")
     return ss
End Function
```

N.B. [SecureString class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) requires a reference to `System.Security.dll` and an import of the namespace `System.Security`

Comment: Thanks, That was it!  I added a `StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True` to see it and now I can save it.