# How to check whether a user is logged into a computer remotely

Tags: .net, vb.net, remote-access

I'm new to VB.NET, and I am creating a tool to check if a user is logged into a computer.

I am using `Label3.Text = Environment.UserDomainName + "\" + Environment.UserName` to check locally, but I would like to know how to do it remotely.

I know how to do it using the Command Prompt `QUSER /SERVER:Computer_name`. Any idea how to do the same remotely?

I could not find something similar here, for that reason I have create this.

I am not looking for a particular user; I would like to know which user is logged in if possible, but if this can't be done I would just like to know if *anyone* is logged to this computer.

For example:

1. pcname001 - none /// pcname001- no
2. pcname002- user_name ///pcname002- yes
3. pcname003- user_name /// pcname003 - yes
4. pcname004-user_name /// pcname004- yes
5. pcname005- none /// pcname005- no

Answer (score 0):

So you’re looking to see if a particular user is logged into a remote session? What you’re doing now pulls the current logged in user running your application, so you’ll want to consider how to know which user to look for. If you’re showing any user, you’ll have issues showing more than one with a label. Consider reviewing this other question/answer for querying sessions

[How can I run "query session" using vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902306/how-can-i-run-query-session-using-vb-net)